# Fall in error after installing node-sass file

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, npm, node-sass

i am trying to run ionic serve with a new project but i keep on falling with this error

[image]

so i tried the following

1. Removed node module folder and run `sudo npm install`.
2. `npm cache clean`
3. `sudo npm install gulp-cli`

Tried with the above could some one say where i am wrong 
I started with `ionic start fileName blank`

my config are

- ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic
- Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.1.1
- @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.6
- @angular/cli                  : 7.3.6
- @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
- @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.4.0

System:

- NodeJS : v10.11.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
- npm    : 6.4.1
- OS     : macOS Mojave

please someone help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

try installing it to your node modals with 
`npm install node-sass` command in your project directory

Or if that doesnt work try installing it globally with `npm install -g node-sass`